# How to change the label of a checkbox in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

Note: Willing to use jQuery, whatever is easier.

I have a form which when submitted, creates a checkbox input. The text of the checkbox should be equal to that of another text input when the form is submitted.

The checkbox is created as expected when I submit the form but it is blank and doesn't contain the text from the corresponding text area.

For a checkbox i'm not sure if I should be using .text, .innerhtml, .val etc and the previous questions I saw on here seemed unnecessarily complicated.

HTML:

```
<div id="listContainer">
    <form id="listForm">
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
        <input id="listInput" class="textarea" placeholder="Add your list item here, then click submit.">
        <div id="checkboxContainer">
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

JS:

```
//ADD LIST ITEM
$("#listForm").submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if ($("#listInput").val() == "") {
        alert("Please enter the item name, then click 'Add'.");
    } else {
        listCount++;
        var input = $("#listInput").val();

        console.log("List Count: " + listCount);
        console.log(input);

        var cb = document.createElement('input');
        cb.id = 'input' + listCount;
        cb.type = 'checkbox';
        document.getElementById("checkboxContainer").appendChild(cb);

        var label = document.createElement('label');
        label.id = 'label' + listCount;
        $("#label" + listCount).attr("for", "input" + listCount).html(input);
        document.getElementById("checkboxContainer").appendChild(label);

        //Store the list count
        localStorage.setItem("listCount", listCount);

        //Store the list title
        localStorage.setItem("input" + listCount, input); //"Note " + noteCount + ": " + 

        this.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: ... checkboxes don't have text... the checkbox consists of just the square box that you can click.

Comment: Create a label for the checkbox

Comment: You need another inline element with ID after your checkbox and change innerHTML of this element

Comment: I think I mean the label of the checkbox, is there a way I can change it. @MaxZoom As you can see from the function, I use createElement to create an input element which has a type of checkbox.

Comment: Create a new label just as you created the input, give it some text, and set its `for` attribute to be the same as the checkbox's `id`.

Comment: @Santi thank you, but how do I 'give it text'? I would like the text to equal the value inside the 'input' variable

Comment: `$("<label />").attr("for", "input" + listCount).html(input).appendTo("#checkboxContainer");` - something along these lines.

Comment: @Santi Updated my question code so you can see easier, still showing blank unfortunatley

Comment: I'll submit an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var label = document.createElement('label');
label.id = 'label' + listCount;
$("#label" + listCount).attr("for", "input" + listCount).html(input);
document.getElementById("checkboxContainer").appendChild(label);
```

These four lines can be cleaned up and fixed. The issue here is quite simple, however your constant back-and-forth between jQuery and plain JS makes things very difficult to read. I would suggest writing DOM manipulation in one or the other, but never both.

The error here is on the third line, which uses the selector `$("label" + listCount)`. This selector will look for this element *on the page*, however you've only created the element - you haven't added it to the page yet.

---

Let's correct this and rewrite it in jQuery:

```
$("<label />")                            //create new label
    .attr("id", "label" + listCount)      //set ID
    .attr("for", "input" + listCount)     //set For
    .html(input)                          //set contents
    .appendTo("#checkboxContainer");      //add to checkbox container
```

---

Consider using the example above to rewrite your checkbox creation as well, that way you can avoid the mixture of jQuery/plain JS.

Comment: Soo much better, thank you very much for taking the time to produce a clear answer. I would prefer to use solely jQuery if possible but I often only know the vanilla syntax. Thank you again @Santi

Comment: @EthanBristow Not a problem. Perhaps this example, along with the code comments, can teach you a bit about jQuery - enough to help you rewrite some of the other code around this portion to match!

Comment: Will do! Once it's finished it will hopefully be all jQuery :)

Comment: @EthanBristow [Have a look](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/mvvprbzr/2/) and make sure to read the comments!

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a few other functions like this as well so I'm going to work on changing them all over now. Also by looking at your fiddle you also helped me understand jQuery variables, I've never really looked into them before and didn't understand exactly what they did but it makes more sense now :)